# timeout while uploading big files to owncloud

Tags: php, nginx, timeout, owncloud

I have installed ownlcoud on my debian Server with mysql, nginx and php-fpm. After everything worked fine, I tried uploading large files (about 12 GB). 
I had to make so adjustments in the php.ini and the sites-available/default file.

```
    client_max_body_size 16400M; # set max upload size
    fastcgi_buffers 128 4K;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 4000;
    proxy_connect_timeout 4000;
    proxy_read_timeout 4000;
    proxy_send_timeout 4000;
    proxy_buffer_size 64k;
    proxy_buffers   4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    client_body_temp_path /ownclouddata/temp;
```

I think the proxy settings should not be important in my case, because I don’t use the server as a proxy.

I changed post_max_size and upload_max_filesize in the php.ini. Now everything works fine, when uploading big files from a client on the same host.

Unfortunately uploading the same file over the web fails. The upload proceeds for about 10 up to 15 minutes (round about 90 percent). Then it seems to restart without any notification. This behavior repeats endless.

Is there any upload timeout in nginx?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by myself. Our proxy seems to be the problem. Tshark shows a lot of connection resets. As soon as I’m at home with direct internet access everything works fine. I will ask our network administrator to proof this strange proxy behavior next week. 
Thanks for the links.